# HelpSystem doesn't work in Delphi XE2 with a few projects

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, help-system

Create any application in Delphi XE2 and press F1 to run help system. You'll see the help article or the following window (for search string 'function'):

[image]

I have an application for Delphi XE2. When I open it and press F1 help system opens only the following window (for search string 'function'):

[image]

If you'll open the first project again (after the second) help system opens the same window as on the second project (incorrect).

I have tried to delete the following files: .dproj, .dof, .identcache, .otares - but with no success. How to fix this issue?

**More info:**

Context help doesn't work on IDE while you're using BPL with `HtmlHelpViewer` unit on uses clause. BPL is design-time and run-time both. Should I create 2 separate BPLs - the first for design-time with conditional directives and the second for using on the application? Is this a Delphi XE2 issue and should it be fixed by Embarcadero?

Comment: This is a question that really can't be answered here. It's a [vendor support question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128579/172661). I'd suggest you check the Embarcadero Delphi forums; they have a specific forum for discussions and questions about documentation.

Comment: Even if you don't "have support" you can still use the forums.  Stack overflow is not a discussion forum, but THIS IS: https://forums.embarcadero.com/index.jspa

Comment: Please look to the "More info" section. Now this is a question for developers - not for the support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Delphi XE2 issue is caused when any design-time BPL using `HtmlHelpViewer` unit. There are 2 solvations:

1. Create 2 separate BPLs for design-time and for run-time.
2. Replace `HtmlHelpViewer` unit by your own and call `HtmlHelp` API directly.

P.S. Thanks to **David Heffernan** for the second method. Embarcadero doesn't want to fix the issue on the IDE or the unit.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps some of the answers to a related help issue that I asked about help earlier this year would be helpful in solving your problem: [How to fix broken context sensitive help in IDE of Delphi 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643667/how-to-fix-broken-context-sensitive-help-in-ide-of-delphi-2010)